Product calculation issue in a Woocommerce custom pluging
I'm a beginner in the world of PHP so forgive me if this is too basic.
I got help to write some code for a Wordpress / Woocommerce plugin that can calculate the square meter (m2) price of the product, using input fields like height, width, quantity, material and finishing.
The current code can show the price at frontend, but when added to the basket the calculation is missing the material and finishing cost. It's like the $material_price and $finish_price is not getting the right value. Also the code shows the price dynamic at the product page, but also live in the basket.
Here is the code:
// Safety control
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit hvis filen tilgås direkte
}

// Table to save M2 prices
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_custom_m2_pricing';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        product_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        enabled tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        min_price float NOT NULL,
        min_unit_price float NOT NULL,
        intervals text NOT NULL,
        materials text NOT NULL,
        finishes text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_install' );

// Add tab to product
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_product_tab( $tabs ) {
    $tabs['m2_pricing'] = array(
        'label'    => __( 'M2 Beregning', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ),
        'target'   => 'm2_pricing_product_data',
        'class'    => array( 'show_if_simple', 'show_if_variable' ),
        'priority' => 21,
    );
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_product_tab' );

// Contents for the M2 price tab
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_product_tab_content() {
    global $post;

    $enabled = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_m2_pricing_enabled', true ) === 'yes';
    $min_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_m2_pricing_min_price', true );
    $min_unit_price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_m2_pricing_min_unit_price', true );
    $intervals = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_m2_pricing_intervals', true );
    $intervals = !empty($intervals) ? json_decode($intervals, true) : array();
    $materials = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_m2_pricing_materials', true );
    $materials = !empty($materials) ? json_decode($materials, true) : array();
    $finishes = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_m2_pricing_finishes', true );
    $finishes = !empty($finishes) ? json_decode($finishes, true) : array();
    ?>
    <div id="m2_pricing_product_data" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">
        <div class="options_group">
            <p class="form-field">
                <label for="_m2_pricing_enabled"><?php _e( 'Aktiver M2 Beregning', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="_m2_pricing_enabled" name="_m2_pricing_enabled" <?php checked( $enabled, true ); ?> />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="options_group">
            <p class="form-field">
                <label for="_m2_pricing_min_price"><?php _e( 'Minimumspris (kr)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" id="_m2_pricing_min_price" name="_m2_pricing_min_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_price ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="options_group">
            <p class="form-field">
                <label for="_m2_pricing_min_unit_price"><?php _e( 'Minimum enhedspris (kr/m2)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
                <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" id="_m2_pricing_min_unit_price" name="_m2_pricing_min_unit_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_unit_price ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="options_group">
            <div id="m2_pricing_intervals">
                <h4><?php _e( 'Prisintervaller', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></h4>
                <table class="widefat">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Fra (m2)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Til (m2)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Pris (kr/m2)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Handling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if ( ! empty( $intervals ) ) {
                            foreach ( $intervals as $interval ) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_interval_from[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $interval['from'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_interval_to[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $interval['to'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_interval_price[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $interval['price'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="button remove_interval"><?php _e( 'Fjern', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_interval_from[]" /></td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_interval_to[]" /></td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_interval_price[]" /></td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="button remove_interval"><?php _e( 'Fjern', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="button add_interval"><?php _e( 'Tilføj interval', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="options_group">
            <div id="m2_pricing_materials">
                <h4><?php _e( 'Materialer', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></h4>
                <table class="widefat">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Materiale', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Pris (%)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Handling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if ( ! empty( $materials ) ) {
                            foreach ( $materials as $material ) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="m2_pricing_material_name[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $material['name'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_material_price[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $material['price'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="button remove_material"><?php _e( 'Fjern', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="m2_pricing_material_name[]" /></td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_material_price[]" /></td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="button remove_material"><?php _e( 'Fjern', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="button add_material"><?php _e( 'Tilføj materiale', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="options_group">
            <div id="m2_pricing_finishes">
                <h4><?php _e( 'Efterbehandlinger', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></h4>
                <table class="widefat">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Efterbehandling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Pris (%)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                            <th><?php _e( 'Handling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if ( ! empty( $finishes ) ) {
                            foreach ( $finishes as $finish ) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="m2_pricing_finish_name[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $finish['name'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_finish_price[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $finish['price'] ); ?>" /></td>
                                    <td><button type="button" class="button remove_finish"><?php _e( 'Fjern', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name="m2_pricing_finish_name[]" /></td>
                                <td><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="m2_pricing_finish_price[]" /></td>
                                <td><button type="button" class="button remove_finish"><?php _e( 'Fjern', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" class="button add_finish"><?php _e( 'Tilføj efterbehandling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_product_tab_content' );

// Save M2 prices and activation status
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_save_product( $post_id ) {
    $enabled = isset( $_POST['_m2_pricing_enabled'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_m2_pricing_enabled', $enabled );

    if ( isset( $_POST['_m2_pricing_min_price'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_m2_pricing_min_price', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_m2_pricing_min_price'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['_m2_pricing_min_unit_price'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_m2_pricing_min_unit_price', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_m2_pricing_min_unit_price'] ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['m2_pricing_interval_from'] ) ) {
        $intervals = array();
        $from = $_POST['m2_pricing_interval_from'];
        $to = $_POST['m2_pricing_interval_to'];
        $prices = $_POST['m2_pricing_interval_price'];

        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $from ); $i++ ) {
            if ( $from[ $i ] !== '' && $to[ $i ] !== '' && $prices[ $i ] !== '' ) {
                $intervals[] = array(
                    'from'  => floatval( $from[ $i ] ),
                    'to'    => floatval( $to[ $i ] ),
                    'price' => floatval( $prices[ $i ] ),
                );
            }
        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_m2_pricing_intervals', wp_json_encode( $intervals ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['m2_pricing_material_name'] ) ) {
        $materials = array();
        $names = $_POST['m2_pricing_material_name'];
        $prices = $_POST['m2_pricing_material_price'];

        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $names ); $i++ ) {
            if ( $names[ $i ] !== '' && $prices[ $i ] !== '' ) {
                $materials[] = array(
                    'name'  => sanitize_text_field( $names[ $i ] ),
                    'price' => floatval( $prices[ $i ] ),
                );
            }
        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_m2_pricing_materials', wp_json_encode( $materials ) );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['m2_pricing_finish_name'] ) ) {
        $finishes = array();
        $names = $_POST['m2_pricing_finish_name'];
        $prices = $_POST['m2_pricing_finish_price'];

        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $names ); $i++ ) {
            if ( $names[ $i ] !== '' && $prices[ $i ] !== '' ) {
                $finishes[] = array(
                    'name'  => sanitize_text_field( $names[ $i ] ),
                    'price' => floatval( $prices[ $i ] ),
                );
            }
        }

        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_m2_pricing_finishes', wp_json_encode( $finishes ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_save_product' );

/**
 * Add input fields to the product page
 */
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_add_fields() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_m2_pricing_enabled', true ) !== 'yes' ) {
        return;
    }

    $intervals = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_m2_pricing_intervals', true );
    $intervals = !empty($intervals) ? json_decode($intervals, true) : array();

    $materials = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_m2_pricing_materials', true );
    $materials = !empty($materials) ? json_decode($materials, true) : array();

    $finishes = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_m2_pricing_finishes', true );
    $finishes = !empty($finishes) ? json_decode($finishes, true) : array();
    ?>
    <div id="m2_pricing_fields">
        <label for="m2_width"><?php _e( 'Bredde (m)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
        <input type="number" id="m2_width" name="m2_width" step="0.01" min="0" required />

        <label for="m2_height"><?php _e( 'Højde (m)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
        <input type="number" id="m2_height" name="m2_height" step="0.01" min="0" required />

        <label for="m2_quantity"><?php _e( 'Antal', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
        <input type="number" id="m2_quantity" name="m2_quantity" min="1" value="1" required />

        <label for="m2_material"><?php _e( 'Materiale', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
        <select id="m2_material" name="m2_material">
            <?php foreach ( $materials as $material ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $material['name'] ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $material['price'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $material['name'] ); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <label for="m2_finish"><?php _e( 'Efterbehandling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ); ?></label>
        <select id="m2_finish" name="m2_finish">
            <?php foreach ( $finishes as $finish ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $finish['name'] ); ?>" data-price="<?php echo esc_attr( $finish['price'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $finish['name'] ); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <input type="hidden" id="m2_min_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_m2_pricing_min_price', true ) ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="m2_min_unit_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_m2_pricing_min_unit_price', true ) ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="m2_intervals" value='<?php echo esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $intervals ) ); ?>' />
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_add_fields' );

/**
 * Calculation of the price based on user input
 */
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_calculate_price() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        function updatePrice() {
            var width = parseFloat($('#m2_width').val());
            var height = parseFloat($('#m2_height').val());
            var quantity = parseInt($('#m2_quantity').val());
            var material = parseFloat($('#m2_material').find(':selected').data('price'));
            var finish = parseFloat($('#m2_finish').find(':selected').data('price'));
    
            if (isNaN(width) || isNaN(height) || isNaN(quantity) || isNaN(material) || isNaN(finish)) {
                return;
            }
    
            var m2 = width * height * quantity;
            var basePrice = 0;
            var minPrice = parseFloat($('#m2_min_price').val());
            var minUnitPrice = parseFloat($('#m2_min_unit_price').val());
    
            var intervals = JSON.parse($('#m2_intervals').val());
            for (var i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
                var interval = intervals[i];
                if (m2 >= interval.from && m2 <= interval.to) {
                    basePrice = interval.price * m2;
                    break;
                }
            }
    
            // Check if basePrice / quantity is less than minUnitPrice
            if ((basePrice / quantity) < minUnitPrice) {
                basePrice = minUnitPrice * quantity;
            }
    
            if (basePrice < minPrice) {
                basePrice = minPrice;
            }

            // Apply material and finish adjustments
            basePrice *= (1 + material / 100);
            basePrice *= (1 + finish / 100);
    
            $('.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text(basePrice.toFixed(2) + ' kr');
        }
    
        $('#m2_width, #m2_height, #m2_quantity, #m2_material, #m2_finish').on('change input', updatePrice);
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_calculate_price');

/**
 * Validation of input fields before the product is added to the basket
 */
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_m2_pricing_enabled', true ) === 'yes' ) {
        if ( empty( $_POST['m2_width'] ) || empty( $_POST['m2_height'] ) || empty( $_POST['m2_quantity'] ) || empty( $_POST['m2_material'] ) || empty( $_POST['m2_finish'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Alle felter skal udfyldes.', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }

        $width = floatval( $_POST['m2_width'] );
        $height = floatval( $_POST['m2_height'] );
        $quantity = intval( $_POST['m2_quantity'] );

        if ( $width <= 0 || $height <= 0 || $quantity <= 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Bredde, højde og antal skal være større end 0.', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Save the user's input in the basket
 */
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if ( get_post_meta( $product_id, '_m2_pricing_enabled', true ) === 'yes' ) {
        $cart_item_data['m2_pricing'] = array(
            'width'    => floatval( $_POST['m2_width'] ),
            'height'   => floatval( $_POST['m2_height'] ),
            'quantity' => intval( $_POST['m2_quantity'] ),
            'material' => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m2_material'] ),
            'finish'   => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['m2_finish'] ),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Show the user's input in the basket
 */
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item_data ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item_data['m2_pricing'] ) ) {
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'  => __( 'Bredde (m)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ),
            'value' => $cart_item_data['m2_pricing']['width'],
        );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'  => __( 'Højde (m)', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ),
            'value' => $cart_item_data['m2_pricing']['height'],
        );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'  => __( 'Antal', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ),
            'value' => $cart_item_data['m2_pricing']['quantity'],
        );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'  => __( 'Materiale', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ),
            'value' => $cart_item_data['m2_pricing']['material'],
        );
        $item_data[] = array(
            'name'  => __( 'Efterbehandling', 'wc-custom-m2-pricing' ),
            'value' => $cart_item_data['m2_pricing']['finish'],
        );
    }
    return $item_data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_get_item_data', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Calculate custom price in basket
 */
function wc_custom_m2_pricing_calculate_cart_item_price($cart_object) {
    foreach ($cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        if (isset($cart_item['m2_pricing'])) {
            $width = floatval($cart_item['m2_pricing']['width']);
            $height = floatval($cart_item['m2_pricing']['height']);
            $quantity = intval($cart_item['m2_pricing']['quantity']);
            $material_price = floatval($cart_item['m2_pricing']['material']);
            $finish_price = floatval($cart_item['m2_pricing']['finish']);

            $m2 = $width * $height * $quantity;
            $basePrice = 0;
            $minPrice = floatval(get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], '_m2_pricing_min_price', true));
            $minUnitPrice = floatval(get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], '_m2_pricing_min_unit_price', true));

            $intervals = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], '_m2_pricing_intervals', true);
            $intervals = !empty($intervals) ? json_decode($intervals, true) : array();
            foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
                if ($m2 >= $interval['from'] && $m2 <= $interval['to']) {
                    $basePrice = $interval['price'] * $m2;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Check if basePrice / quantity is less than minUnitPrice
            if (($basePrice / $quantity) < $minUnitPrice) {
                $basePrice = $minUnitPrice * $quantity;
            }

            if ($basePrice < $minPrice) {
                $basePrice = $minPrice;
            }

            // Apply material and finish adjustments
            $basePrice *= (1 + $material_price / 100);
            $basePrice *= (1 + $finish_price / 100);

            // Set the calculated price for the cart item
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($basePrice);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'wc_custom_m2_pricing_calculate_cart_item_price', 10, 1);

I've tried some basic rewrite of the calculation, but I simply don't know how to fix this and would highly appreciate any help.

Why are you creating a custom database table, that you don't use in your code?

As I understood the database table contains the information from the backend, so it can be used later on. Example if prices or intervals changes.

Your code only creates a custom database empty table, that is not populated by your code. Also, in your admin product custom tab settings the buttons "Fjern" and "Tilføj interval" doesn't have any effect (it seems that some JavaScript is missing). Your current code is too broad and requires appropriated product settings (values), to try reproducing your issue. You should try to update your question to only include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Also try to better explain things, as your question is a bit unclear, actually. As stack overflow is an English Q & A, you should translate the displayed elements in English, as this is made and useful for an English community.

Thank you, I will try to get some better code before we can proceed. Thank you for your help so far.
